# pyaudio playing sound in a systemd unit is veeery low, unless I log in with ssh

Tags: python, audio, raspbian, systemd, pyaudio

I run a Python script in a systemd unit on Raspbian bullseye (Raspberry Pi zero W + Adafruit voice bonnet). My problem is that when I push the button to play a file, it will play some reeeeally low volume which I can only hear some scratch. The funny thing is if before trying to play the sound, I log in to the Rpi with ssh
and then try to play the sound, it works ! Just like if I needed to login ssh to have a proper audio player.

This is my service file :

```
[Unit]
Description=bondz-client
Requires=sys-devices-platform-soc-soc:sound-sound-card1-controlC1.device
After=sys-devices-platform-soc-soc:sound-sound-card1-controlC1.device

[Service]
User=pyapp
Group=pyapp
Type=idle
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/Documents/Talkie.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/Documents/

StandardOutput=append:/var/log/pyapp.log
StandardError=append:/var/log/pyapp.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For information I retrieved the required sound card with the command `systemctl -l |grep sound-card` which shows :

```
sys-devices-platform-soc-20902000.hdmi-sound-card0-controlC0.device                          loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/soc/20902000.hdmi/sound/card0/controlC0
sys-devices-platform-soc-soc:sound-sound-card1-controlC1.device                              loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/soc/soc:sound/sound/card1/controlC1
```

I isolated the bug to have this script that plays a wave file in loop. As long as I am not connected in ssh, I can barely hear a noise of the sound, and immediately after connecting with ssh the sound is clear...

```
from Player import Player
import logging

import io
import wave
import logging
import traceback
import pyaudio

player = Player()
logger = logging.getLogger("Player")
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

def play():
    playWaveFile("tests/myrecording.wav", play)


def playWaveFile(filepath, callback):
    info = audio.get_default_output_device_info()
    try:
        wave_file = wave.open(filepath, "rb")
        playStream = audio.open(          
        format=audio.get_format_from_width(wave_file.getsampwidth()),
            channels=wave_file.getnchannels(),
            rate=wave_file.getframerate(),
            output=True,
        )
        data = wave_file.readframes(1024)
        while data:
            playStream.write(data)
            data = wave_file.readframes(1024)
        # Cleanup
        playStream.stop_stream()
        playStream.close()
        callback()
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()


play()
```

Also, if I remove the `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5` in the service and try to play the audio file I get this error :

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py", line 824, in get_default_output_device_info
    device_index = pa.get_default_output_device()
OSError: No Default Output Device Available
```

A manual systemctl restart using ssh will make it work normally...

Thank you for your help  !